# My Nintex Custom Action not reading in Workflow Variable in SingleLineInput

Tags: sharepoint-2010, nintex-workflow

I've written a custom workflow action that takes in several values, mostly using the SingleLineInput control.

When I assign literal values, I have no issues, but when I try to assign a Workflow Variable, I don't get the actual value of the variable, I get the literal text - something like {WorkflowVariable:XmlValue} - assuming my variable was names XmlValue.

I'm not sure what I could possibly be doing wrong. Any ideas?

Here's code snippets:

The javascript for retrieving the value from the SingleLineInput

```
function TPAWriteConfig() {
    configXml.selectSingleNode("/NWActionConfig/Parameters/Parameter[@Name='FieldValue']/PrimitiveValue/@Value").text = getRTEValue('<%=fieldValue.ClientID%>');
    SaveErrorHandlingSection();
    return true;

}
```

The server control:

```
<Nintex:ConfigurationProperty ID="ConfigurationProperty3" runat="server" FieldTitle="Field Value" RequiredField="True">
    <TemplateControlArea>
        <Nintex:SingleLineInput runat="server" id="fieldValue"></Nintex:SingleLineInput>
    </TemplateControlArea>
</Nintex:ConfigurationProperty>
```

From my adapter class:

```
private const string FieldValueProperty = "FieldValue";


NWActionConfig config = new NWActionConfig(this);
config.Parameters[2] = new ActivityParameter();
config.Parameters[2].Name = FieldValueProperty;
config.Parameters[2].PrimitiveValue = new PrimitiveValue();
config.Parameters[2].PrimitiveValue.Value = string.Empty;
config.Parameters[2].PrimitiveValue.ValueType = SPFieldType.Text.ToString();
```

From the activity class:

```
public static DependencyProperty FieldValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FieldValue", typeof (string),
                                                                                              typeof (
                                                                                                  WriteOnePdfFieldActivity));



public string FieldValue
{
    get { return (string) GetValue(FieldValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FieldValueProperty, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel a little silly answering my own question, but for the sake of anyone else having the same issues. Here's how it works:

- If you're putting a literal value in the field, just use the value
- If you're using any other kind of assignment, do a lookup based on the value.

The code below demonstrates:

```
var fieldValue = FieldValue.StartsWith("{") ? ctx.AddContextDataToString(FieldValue, true) : FieldValue;
```

This extract the value from the workflow context. Hope this helps.

Comment: Where have I to add the solution? Have I to add it int he js function (which) on in the c# code?